# Only displaying enough rows in HTML table visible on the screen?

Tags: css, reactjs, responsive

I'm working on a design where I prefetch `N` elements that display in a table. The height of the table is responsive. Currently, I have a y-axis overflow that enables scrolling, but the UX is not ideal.

My goal is to show only enough items that would fit within the table. What's the best way to consider doing this?

Currently, my thought is to attach a `ref` on the heading of the table, a single row and table itself. With that, I can get the entire table height.

1. `get table height` - 1000px
2. `get heading height` - 20px
3. `get row height` - 20px

With these numbers, I know that I could fit `49` items. `1000-(heading-height)/(row-height)`.

This seems over-engineered. What's the best way to do this?

Comment: Yes, this is over-engineered. Let the user scroll. Just look how search engines do it.

Comment: Thanks, good to hear a second opinion.